# order of initialisation of members with compiler generated default initialisation

Tags: c++, initialization

Given the following:

```
class D { ... };

struct C
{
    D d;
    int a;
    C() : a(5) {}
};
```

The compiler will generate code to initialise `C::d`, but does it `d` get initialised before or after `a`? Or is it implementation defined? or undefined?

I'm asking because I have seen at least one compiler say my initialisers do not match the order of the data members.

Comment: Which particular compiler says that about this particular code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of initialization is the order of declaration. That means that 'd' will be initialized before 'a' in your example. Even if you specify the other order in the initialization list. In that case most compilers will print a warning.

Comment: the compiler is printing a warning even though I'm only initialising one variable

Comment: @Tom: hum, I can only check with g++. It only warns me if I initialize d after a. I cannot check the C++ standard, I do not know if gcc is right. It does not complain when I compile your example even with pedantic options. You have to check the C++ standard to get the law ...

Comment: Looks like I'll have to produce a minimum test case and whine at the manufactor then. thanks.